# How can I write a shortcut to compile and run a program in a separate terminal window in Vim? (OSX)

Tags: c++, vim, macvim

This Sublime Text build system compiles a C++ program, then opens a new window in Terminal.app and runs it there upon pressing ctrl+b.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++-11 -std=c++20 '${file}' -o '${file_base_name}' && echo 'cd \"${file_path}/\"' > '/tmp/${file_base_name}' && echo './\"${file_base_name}\"' >> '/tmp/${file_base_name}' && echo read >> '/tmp/${file_base_name}' && chmod +x '/tmp/${file_base_name}' && open -a Terminal.app '/tmp/${file_base_name}'"
}
```

How would you write something similar for Vim?

Comment: Would the built-in terminal be OK or do you absolutely want to open a separate terminal? Also, what did you try?

Comment: @romainl I made my own command to compile and run my program within Vim's builtin terminal (attaching in post).

It works, but I'm unable to paste in any input, which is an issue. Both the built in terminal and a separate one would really be okay if pasting in input is supported.

Comment: The command you posted doesn't use the built-in terminal. See `:help :terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a few options, so use whatever suits your needs the most.

You can use **vim's built in terminal** `:terminal` (or `:term`; see `:help :terminal`), which is probably the easier way:

```
:term g++-11 %:p && ./a.out<CR>
```

Or you can use **`:compiler` with `:make`** (see `:help :compile` and `:help 'makeprg'`):

```
:compiler gcc
:let $CXXFLAGS='-std=c++20 -Wall -Werror'
:make
```

Answer (score 1):

Wish this plugin in neovim can help you:             https://github.com/michaelb/sniprun

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the extension looks nice. However, I'm using MacVim, (which I think uses regular Vim instead of Neovim) so I'm not sure if it would work.